# The import org.springframework.security cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven

I get an error the

> import org.springframework.security cannot be resolved.

I searched and maybe I am missing a dependency and have to add a it, I do not know, please help me. I am giving you my pom.xml file and my java class If anyone can help me I would be very grateful

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Music</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Music</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my java class

```
package masters.rest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import masters.beans.CommentBean;
import masters.beans.UserBean;
import masters.repositories.CommentRepo;


@RestController
public class Comment {

    CommentRepo commentRepo;

    public Comment(CommentRepo commentRepo) {
        this.commentRepo = commentRepo;
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/comment/delete")
    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> deleteComment(
            @RequestParam(value = "id") int id,
            HttpSession session
            ){

        UserBean user = (UserBean)session.getAttribute("user");

        if(user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        Optional<CommentBean> optionalComment = commentRepo.findById(id);

        if(optionalComment.isPresent()) {

            CommentBean comment = optionalComment.get();

            if(comment.getUser().getId() == user.getId()) {
                commentRepo.delete(comment);

                return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
            }else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT);
            }

        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing `security` dependency in `pom.xml`. Add following to your `pom.xml` and update maven project. It should resolve the dependacy.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```